# A card is drawn at random from a standard deck of 52 playing cards. It is replaced, the deck is shuffled and a card is drawn again.

Tags: probability

A card is drawn at random from a standard deck of 52 playing cards. It is replaced, the deck is shuffled and a card is drawn again. What is the probability that:

(a) both cards are spades,

(b) neither card is a heart,

(c) both cards are the same suit?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Don't get scared by the fact that we are using playing cards here... Can you answer the almost identical question of asking "*If you flip two coins in a row what is the probability that both coins are heads?  That neither are heads?  That both coins match?*"

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: The probability that both coins are heads is 1/4. I didn't understand what you meant by "That neither are heads? That both coins match?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your approach?

You should look at the process you are executing. For example: if your process of doing actions matches the following conditions, you can model your process as a binomial distribution and can look for answers:

1: The number of observations n is fixed.

2: Each observation is independent.

3: Each observation represents one of two outcomes ("success" or "failure").

4: The probability of "success" p is the same for each outcome.

So let's take a look:

1: The number of observations n is fixed: it seems that way. The number of observations is 2.

2: Each observation is independent: that seems clear from your question

3: Each observation represents one of two outcomes ("success" or "failure"):

a) if the first draw is a spade: success, if the second draw is a spade: success

b) if the first draw is not a heart: success, if the second draw is not a heart: success

c) this is a little bit easier, because the first draw doesn't matter which suit it is, so the question is: what is the change on succes (drawing the same suit) the second time. So this is just $ \frac{12}{52} = $ 23.08%. But also this can be done with the binomial distribution.

4: The probability of "success" p is the same for each outcome. This is also the case in your question.

So, plugging in the binomial distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

you get:

a) 6.25%

b) 56.25%

c) 25%

Could you reproduce my results?

Comment: btw: I know that it's easier to just do $\frac{13}{52}*\frac{13}{52}$ and $\frac{39}{52}*\frac{39}{52}$ and $\frac{13}{52}$ but I feel this approach is better

Comment: I think the second explanation makes more sense. How did you get 13/52*13/52 and 39/52*39/52 and 13/52 can you please explain it further.

Comment: I know it makes more sense but you should try to understand the first one. How did I get the numbers? what is the chance on drawing a spade from the deck for example?

Comment: The chance will be 13/52

Comment: so doing this 2 draws in a row: you get $\frac{13}{52}*\frac{13}{52}$. Now what is the chance on drawing NOT a heart card? So drawing one of the other 3 suits.

Comment: It will be 39/52

Comment: so then you do the same trick. Now, for the last one: it doesn't matter what your first draw is: so the chance on picking a card is 100% obviously. But the second draw must be the same suit as the first. So let's say you draw a spade the first time: what is the chance on drawing the second time a spade? $\frac{13}{52}$ obviously: so $1* \frac{13}{52} = 0.25$. and there you have it.

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks a lot for spending the time to help me, appreciate it.

Comment: no problem. don't forget to accept the answer if your problem is solved.

Comment: How do I do that I new to this webpage? Do I just press the tick?

Comment: yes, you have accepted the answer.